# CreateRemoteThread, WriteProcessMemory, VirtualAllocEx - why use them?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, win32-process

Recently I have been reading up articles about DLL injection and I understand them fairly well.

However, what I don't understand is why APIs such as CreateRemoteThread, WriteProcessMemory(in being able to write to the memory of another process) and VirtualAllocEx(in being able to allocat memory in the context of another process) were implemented in the first place.

What was the original need for such APIs? Just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WriteProcessMemory` was made for ring3 debuggers that need to securely write process memory, most commonly for `INT 3` breakpoints or user provided memory edits.

along the same line, `CreateRemoteThread` can also be used for debugging purposes, however, MSDN can enlighten us on `CreateRemoteThread` a bit more:

> A common use of this function is to inject a thread into a process
>   that is being debugged to issue a break. However, this use is not
>   recommended, because the extra thread is confusing to the person
>   debugging the application and there are several side effects to using
>   this technique:
>
> - It converts single-threaded applications into
>     multithreaded applications.
> - It changes the timing and memory layout of
>     the process.
> - It results in a call to the entry point of each DLL in
>     the process.

IIRC, `CreateRemoteThread` is also used by debuggers to hook application native expection handlers, commonly set by `SetExceptionHandler`, which requires call from the target process as the handler is stored in the PEB.

`VirtualAllocEx` is just how windows virtual memory system operates, it needs a context to allocate in, be it in the current process, a child process or a remote process. `VirtualAlloc` in fact is nothing more than a pass through wrapper of the Ex variant, it just passes a special constant that indicates the handle of the caller process is to be used.